# Sending dynamic number of fields

Tags: java, html, angularjs, jstl

I create jsp and insert fields at server side (using jstl):

```html
<c:forEach items="${fields}" var="field">
    <p><c:out value="${field.name}" /></p>
    <p><input type="hidden" ng-model ="name" value = "${field.name}" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model ="value"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

How can i submit data to server like JSON objects:

```js
var array = [
    { name: $scope.name, value: $scope.value },
    { name: $scope.name, value: $scope.value },
    ..........................................
    { name: $scope.name, value: $scope.value }
];
```

Im l looking for most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use spring form, for forming user object.

```
<c:url var="registration" value="/registration"></c:url>
    <form:form role="form" commandName="user" action="${registration}" method="POST">
        <c:forEach items="${fields}" var="field" varStatus="loop">
            <p><c:out value="${field.name}" /> <c:if test="${field.required == true}"><c:out value=" *" /></c:if></p>
            <p><form:input path="name[${loop.index}]" type="hidden" value = "${field.name}" /></p>
            <p><form:input path="value[${loop.index}]" type="text" required = "${field.required}"/></p>
        </c:forEach>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form:form>
```

Object for collect data:

```
public class UserDto {
        private String[] name;
        private String[] value;

        public String[] getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String[] name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String[] getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String[] value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

And controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration (@ModelAttribute("user") UserDto dto){
        User user = new User();
        String[] values = dto.getValue();
        String[] names = dto.getName();
        ArrayList<FieldValue> fieldValues = new ArrayList<FieldValue>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            Field field = fieldDao.findByName(names[i]);
            FieldValue tmp = new FieldValue(values[i], field, user);
            fieldValues.add(tmp);
        }
        user.setFields(fieldValues);
        userDao.save(user);
        return "redirect:/fields";
    }
```